# How do I install Ubuntu Using a CD

Tags: installation, windows, cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

I have recently burned Ubuntu to a CD using the instructions on the downloads website, I made sure that it had burned properly and not just the .iso file (So I could see all the right files, and not just the .iso file) I put in the disc and the OS launched. On the Desktop, i clicked the 'Install Ubuntu' and a window popped up. I selected English and the window dissapeared after I clicked 'Ok'. Did it install or did I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

James Easton

Comment: See [My Answer Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194676/cant-install-ubuntu-ver-12-04-1-both-32bit-and-64-bit-12-04-11-04-and-10-0#comment242792_194676)

Answer (score 0):

You will find full installation procedure in the following answer https://askubuntu.com/a/152902/91632 and If you need any further I am ready